# Not able to resolve conflict in Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-merge, git-merge-conflict, azure-git-deployment

Unable to merge the conflict in `Azure Devops` I have created the `Pull Request` from `api_integration` branch to `development` branch. But there are some conflicts I can see but as my Complete button is disabled, not sure how to deal with code merging here.

I tried to switch to `development` branch in my android studio and pull the request but it says `All files are up to date`.

[image]

Not sure how to resolve this issue of PR with merge conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you should resolve them locally with git commands, see tutorial [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/merge-conflicts).

But - better way is to use the [Pull Request Merge Conflict Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.conflicts-tab) for Azure DevOps.

After the installation you will have "conflicts" tab inside the PR:

[image]