# Pull Request has conflicts, but "View merge changes" is disabled

Tags: git, azure-devops

Using Azure DevOps, I submitted a Pull Request.  The *OverView* says there are merge conflicts, but offers no way to edit/resolve them.  The *View merge changes* item on the "three dots" menu is greyed out.

Any ideas as to why the PR is presenting this way and/or what I can do?

Comment: General answer for graphical webhosts of repos (read GitHub). Your conflict(s) are likely too complicated to be displayed in their GUI. You might have to checkout and pull this branch in a terminal command line and solve the conflicts there.

Comment: Do you have the Pull Request Merge Conflict Extension (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.conflicts-tab) installed?  It provides a way of resolving conflicts from within the pull request (c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63473042/azure-devops-resolve-pull-request-conflict or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64722185/how-do-i-resolve-a-pull-request-merge-conflict-in-azure-dev-ops)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71871488/not-able-to-resolve-conflict-in-azure-devops/71875723#71875723

Answer (score 2):

Install this extension from Marketplace.

[image]

You could check the Conflicts tab in the Pull Request Page.

[image]

[image]